# Не работает обработчик даты

Tags: php, mysql, дата

написал скрипт, который выводит из базы данных дату последнего действия. Но он не работает, пожалуйста помогите решить проблему :)

```
    <?php 
  $mysqldate = 1548841956; # Это дата получаемая из базы данных


  # Перевод даты из базы  в формат времени Unix 
  $time = strtotime($mysqldate);

  # Создаем ассоциативный массив где каждому числу месяца присваем название месяца
  $month_name = array( 
    1 => 'января', 
    2 => 'февраля', 
    3 => 'марта', 
    4 => 'апреля', 
    5 => 'мая', 
    6 => 'июня', 
    7 => 'июля',
    8 => 'августа', 
    9 => 'сентября', 
    10 => 'октября', 
    11 => 'ноября', 
    12 => 'декабря' 
  );

  #Получаем название месяца, здесь используется наш созданный массив
  $month = $month_name[ date( 'n',$time ) ]; 

    $day   = date( 'j',$time ); # С помощью функции date() получаем число дня
    $year  = date( 'Y',$time ); # Получаем год
    $hour  = date( 'G',$time ); # Получаем значение часа
    $min   = date( 'i',$time ); # Получаем минуты

    $date = "$day $month $year, $hour:$min";  # Собираем пазл из переменных

  echo "Последний вход: ".$date; #Выводим преобразованную дату на экран
  ?>
```

На выходе он выводит следующее: Последний вход: 1 января 1970, 3:00

Comment: strtotime - Преобразует текстовое представление даты в метку времени. Вам нужно использовать: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Перевод даты из базы  в формат времени Unix 
$time = strtotime($mysqldate);
```

`$mysqldate` (`$mysqldate = 1548841956;`) **уже в формате времени Unix**. Так что данное преобразование не требуется.

С учетом того что `date()` понимает и сложные форматы даты, ваш код можно упростить до:

```
$mysqldate = 1548841956; # Это дата получаемая из базы данных
# Создаем ассоциативный массив где каждому числу месяца присваем название месяца
$month_name = array(
    1 => 'января',
    2 => 'февраля',
    3 => 'марта',
    4 => 'апреля',
    5 => 'мая',
    6 => 'июня',
    7 => 'июля',
    8 => 'августа',
    9 => 'сентября',
    10 => 'октября',
    11 => 'ноября',
    12 => 'декабря'
);

#Получаем название месяца, здесь используется наш созданный массив
$month = $month_name[ date( 'n', $mysqldate ) ];
echo "Последний вход: " . date("j $month Y, в G:i", $mysqldate);
```

Comment: Хорошо, но мне надо выводить данные в виде: Последний вход 15 января 2019 года в 15:43

Comment: И что вам мешает?

Comment: Не получается, он должен выводить дату "ден месяц год часы:минуты", а выводит точку отсчёта 1 января 1970, 3:00

Comment: А вы понимаете что удалив/закомментировав строку `$time = strtotime($mysqldate);` вы лишились переменной `$time`?

Comment: По факту дата из Unix не переводится

Comment: Благодарю Вас за помощь! Спасибо!

Comment: Галочка слева от ответа покажет остальным посетителям что данный ответ решил вашу проблему.